# The correct way to communicate between several different view controllers in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, casting

I have an app that was extremely simple until today. It had a tab bar view controller with 3 tabs. The middle tab was a camera, and the other 2 were table views. The tab bar view controller was the central hub for all the data in the app. So from there, I would set a table's data array as:

```
(PLEListViewController*)[self.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0] setList:newList];
```

Obviously, `PLEListViewController` is my `UITableView` subclass.

So now, I want to wrap the table views in a `UINavigationController`, which is fairly simple. But now, that line of code turns into:

```
[(PLEListViewController*)((UINavigationController*)[self.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0]).topViewController setList:newList];
```

There are 15 lines in the code that do this, which is not pleasant.

So my question: what is a more elegant way of doing this that I'm missing?

Comment: Do you create view controllers in xib files?

Comment: I would give a chance to NSNotificationCenter.

Comment: This would be a better question in http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You'd have to change FIFTEEN LINES OF CODE???!!!  OMG!!!  How awful!!!

Comment: (Have you considered writing a method on your "root" controller that would, given an index, return the desired controller?)

Comment: @H2CO3: won't work. I'll get exceptions.

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri: storyboard.

Comment: @Shinigami Exceptions? Because of a cast? That's not quite possible. Objective-C is dynamic. The types are there just for making the compiler happy. If an object is of a certain class, it will stay being of that class, however you cast it during compile time.

Comment: @HotLicks: I have done that. I just wanted to know if there was a neater way. Having helper methods does seem to be the only better option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's good that you're asking this and seeing the issue now. Your problem is can be found in your question. The answer to "the correct way to communicate between several different view controllers in Objective C" is "don't." Specifically, your mistake is here:

> The tab bar view controller was the central hub for all the data in the app.

A view controller should never hold any of the data in the app. Your data should live in your model classes. All the view controllers should talk to the model classes. They should very seldom talk to each other. That's the heart of MVC.

So, you move your "list" (whatever that is, doesn't matter) into some model object that all the view controllers know about. That model object can be a singleton, or often better, it can be passed to the view controllers when they are created. When things change, you change the model. And in `viewWillAppear:` you update your view controller to match the current state of the model.

Never assume that a view controller exists when it is not currently on screen. If your design requires that a non-active view controller exist, then your design needs fixing.

Comment: Thank you. This was the kinda answer I was looking for. I guess I should've known better, but in most examples I've seen, view controllers seems to do most of the heavy lifting, so I didn't think of having a separate model object. A few questions, if you don't mind: I've heard singletons should be avoided; why? And can you explain the alternative to singletons a bit more please?

Comment: Most examples put too much into VCs. They do that because they're focused on some detail (like how to segue) and don't want to create extra classes. Singletons shouldn't be avoided. They're a trade-off. You can put your model store in a singleton, or you can create it when the program starts and hand it to each VC that needs it as a property. Passing it around is more flexible (especially for testing). Singletons are usually a little less code. If you pass objects to things that don't use them, just so they can pass them onto things they call, then that's often better done as a singleton.

Answer (score 4):

You need to work with your architecture. Make the appropriate datasource and delegation protocols to ensure your classes can communicate anonymously. What you currently have is very inflexible and it will get worse as your app grows/changes.

Comment: Right... this is kinda my question: what is that correct way of doing this, exactly? I can't think of how protocols can avoid this kind of code. But your comment just gave me the idea that the tab bar view controller maybe should've been the tables' data source. But that would put relevant code in different files. So can you give me a bit more specific guideline?

Comment: Just some ideas: Let's say you have an tabBarController, you can create a protocol that says "PLEListViewControllerDatasource", and set your tabBarController as the datasource. Now, whenever you need to get a value from your object, instead of having a second copy on your PLEListViewController, you just ask its datasource for the records it needs for its tableview.

Comment: The tab bar view controller should definitely not be the table data source. The tab bar view controller is the view controller for the tab bar. It has not business knowing anything about tables. The data source for the table view should be the table view controller or possibly (and rarely) a separate model controller.

Comment: @RobNapier I am sorry if I didn't express myself correctly, but I mean that the tabBarController should be the data source of the tableviewcontroller that contains the table. So, the tableViewController would request to its datasource which one is the array to use for its data.

Comment: I understood. The tab bar controller should not be the source of data for anything except the tab bar. The table view controller should get its data from the model and provide it to the table view.

Answer (score 1):

You want to make things more loosely-coupled, instead of coding explicit traversal of links between your objects in your code.

Assuming you have one data model that is displayed in various places in your application, I think there are 2 approaches that could help...

One is to use your view controller hierarchy.. For example, use `[ self enclosingTabBarController ]` to find your closest parent tab bar controller and get it's data model property. Substitute `-enclosingTabBarController` with what works better for your application.

The other approach would be a "data model as a singleton" approach. For this you can either

- move the data to your application delegate and access it via `((MyApplicationDelegateClass*)[ UIApplication sharedApplication ].delegate).dataModel`

or

- have a singleton data model object for your app, and access it via `[ MyDataModelClass sharedModel ]`

In any case you are moving to a looser coupling, which requires less explicit traversal of links between objects in your app. Less is more!